# Panel with Datastore in extjs

Tags: java, extjs, datastore

My data is not displaying I dont know what is wrong 
my store is

```
Ext.define('store.sa.saDataStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
storeId: 'saDatastore',

requires: ['model.sa.saModel'], 
model: 'model.sa.saModel', 
data : [
        [ 'Address3' ]        
    ]   
});
```

my model is

```
Ext.define(model.sa.saModel', {
extend: 'model.common.Base',


fields: [
         {name: 'address3', type: 'string'},


     ] 
});
```

code is

```
Ext.define('view.sa.saDS', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'saDS',

 requires: [ 'store.sa.saDataStore',
             'model.sa.saModel'],
   title: 'sapage with DATA store ',
    width: 600,
    height: 350,

    store: {
        type: 'saDataStore'
    },
    session: true,

    items: [{  
                xtype:'form',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    width:1000,
                    height:800,
                    title: 'data store',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'displayfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Title',
                         name:  'address3',

                      }]
        }]
   }], 

   listeners: {
        afterrender: function(component, eOpts){
            var store = Ext.getStore('saDatastore');
            console.log(store);
            if(!Ext.isEmpty(store)) {
                var form = component.down('form');
                form.loadRecord(store.last());
                console.log("data upload done ");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code 
dont know what is wrong

Comment: Have you mistaken [tag:java] for [tag:javascript]?

Comment: Your store data array is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like below:-

```
Ext.define('store.sa.saDataStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'saDatastore',    
    requires: ['model.sa.saModel'],
    model: 'model.sa.saModel',
    data: [{
        address3: 'Address 3'
    }]
});

Ext.define('model.sa.saModel', {
    extend: 'model.common.Base',
    fields: [{
        name: 'address3',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});

Ext.define('view.sa.saDS', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'saDS',

    requires: ['store.sa.saDataStore',
        'model.sa.saModel'
    ],
    title: 'sapage with DATA store ',
    width: 600,
    height: 350,

    store: {
        type: 'saDataStore'
    },
    session: true,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            width: 1000,
            height: 800,
            title: 'data store',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Title',
                name: 'address3',

            }]
        }]
    }],

    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (component, eOpts) {
            var store = Ext.getStore('saDatastore');
            console.log(store);
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(store)) {
                var form = component.down('form');
                form.loadRecord(store.last());
                console.log("data upload done ");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[Code snippet](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2foj)

Answer (score 1):

Data config of store accepts the data in the form of array of objects. Modify your syntax as below snippet.

```
data: [{
    address3: 'Address 3'
},{
    address4: 'Address 4'
}]
```